What is the vortex pattern when the flow is passing an axis-symmetric vortex flowmeter?
It is wellknown that in 2D case, the vortices will be formed at the back of the bluff body and detached periodically from either side of the body in a pattern called Kármán vortex street. But what about its 3D similarity?
It is assumed that the flow is leaving the (3D bottom) trailing edge uniformly, so the flow will be forming a corkscrew-like pattern in a later stage to initiate the instability? Will this involve the symmetry breaking?

